# Making Microsoft Azure Graph Client for .net emit $expand

Tags: c#, azure, graph, office365, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to retrieve a (paged) list of all users in the directory, with the manager property expanded. When I run the following HTTP query it works as I want:

```
https://graph.windows.net/DOMAIN/users/?$expand=manager&api-version=2013-11-08
```

However I don't seem to grasp how to make the same query with the [Azure AD Graph client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/). This is what I'm trying:

```
var userResult = _activeDirectoryClient.Users.Expand(x => x.Manager).ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

Comment: What version of the Azure AD Graph Client Library are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.1.1.0. At first I think I was using 2.0.something, but then I switched to the latest to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

I adapted the following from the example at https://github.com/AzureADSamples/ConsoleApp-GraphAPI-DotNet/blob/master/GraphConsoleAppV3/Program.cs, please give it a shot:

```html
         List<IUser> usersList = null;
            IPagedCollection<IUser> searchResults = null;
            try
            {
                IUserCollection userCollection = activeDirectoryClient.Users;
                userResult = userCollection.ExecuteAsync().Result;
                usersList = searchResults.CurrentPage.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError getting User {0} {1}", e.Message,
                    e.InnerException != null ? e.InnerException.Message : "");
            }

            if (usersList != null && usersList.Count > 0)
            {
                do
                {
                    usersList = searchResults.CurrentPage.ToList();
                    foreach (IUser user in usersList)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("User DisplayName: {0}  UPN: {1}  Manager: {2}",
                            user.DisplayName, user.UserPrincipalName, user.Manager);
                    }
                    searchResults = searchResults.GetNextPageAsync().Result;
                } while (searchResults != null);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No users found");
            }
```

Comment: The sample sets the manager just before it fetches the manager, and it has no code to expand the manager property. Because of this I don't understand how this would help me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear in my description: the external sample is a point of reference - I customized a portion of it (what you see on the screen here) to achieve your requirements.

Comment: @KeithTuomi-MVP, can you highlight the changes you made? I don't see a difference between what's here and what's in the sample

Answer (score 2):

The GraphClient does not implement all of the features in the Graph API just yet.
New features are being added to the GraphClient over time and will be announced on the AAD team blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/

And updates will be available in the nuget package ( Microsoft Azure Active Directory Graph Client Library ).

You can make what you need by making Http calls to the url you have in the question and get the response back as Json like this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.windows.net/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("DOMAIN/users/?$expand=manager&api-version=2013-11-08");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
         // TODO: Deserialize the response here...
    }
}
```